# What is necessary to boot Linux on a Mac?

Tags: hard-drive, partition, startup, sd-card, grub

I've seen some various guides online about different ways to boot Ubuntu from an SD card or a USB stick. They have some variation with regards to making it always boot from the external memory or fully installing it on the MacBook, for example. Apple does not seem to provide any official information on how to do this. Ubuntu provides information about downloading Ubuntu to an SD card, but not what it takes on the Mac end.

I'm curious to understand underlying principles. What is necessary to get the Mac to boot Ubuntu, if it is on a USB stick or SD card?

Does the Ubuntu download need to be formatted a certain way, with diskutils? Why?
Does the Mac drive need to be partitioned a certain way? Why?
Does anything need to be done with the booting software, grubloader?

At minimum, is it possible to just download Ubuntu to an SD card, stick it in the computer and turn it on? Why would the computer immediately know to boot from the external memory?

Comment: Have a look at Ubuntu's own tutorial: [Create a bootable USB stick on macOS](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview)

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do it from an SD card, and I didn't see a Ubuntu guide for that, so I would like to understand the specific steps necessary, because guides I found in Google have some particularities that I don't know to what extent some of the steps are necessary. I'd like to know just what is necessary and why.

Comment: There is no difference! Just follow the directions substituting  SD Card where is says USB stick.

Comment: Ok, that's very good to know, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are several tutorials online that tell you how to format a bootable drive and use it to boot up.  They usually instruct the user to download an image, use something like balena Etcher to "flash" it, and then select it as the boot drive during the startup process.

https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=booting+ubuntu+from+usb+mac
This should help you.

Comment: Thanks very much, but those are all USB and I want to do it from an SD card. That's why instead of just a list of steps I would like conceptual understanding of what is even happening when Mac "boots" from any external memory device.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest instructions would be to use Ubunutu's [instruction for transferring to USB stick](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview). Restart the Mac and hold down the option key. Select to boot from the icon labeled `EFI Boot`.

If etcher will not accept an SD card, then try the [command line method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20install%20Ubuntu%20on%20MacBook%20using%20USB%20Stick?_ga=2.138999793.335916142.1627074479-1266414036.1626109728).

You state in the comments that you would like a conceptual understanding of what is even happening when Mac "boots" from any external memory device. Well here goes:

Hold down the option key at startup. This instructs the Mac to boot to the Mac Startup Manager stored in the firmware on the logic board. The Mac startup manager looks for external drives with readable volumes containing the file `\EFI\BOOT\BOOTX64.EFI`. If found, then a icon with the label `EFI Boot` will appear. If you select this icon, then the Mac Startup Manager will instruct the boot loader in the firmware on the logic board to boot from this file. Eventually, Grub will execute and often you are presented with a menu of boot options. You can select to boot from a live version of Ubuntu. Grub will then boot the live version of Ubuntu.

Be aware, often a Linux ISO will offer more than one way to boot. The method used can depend on the model/year Mac you are using. My explanation is just one possible scenario.